# How to find closed loops using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to find self-referential loops with an RDF using:

```
SELECT ?sbj
# query pattern
WHERE {
     ?sbj skos:broader+ ?sbj .
}
```

when I run this on these RDF triples:

```
http://www.example.com/Concept/0001 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader http://www.example.com/Concept/0002
http://www.example.com/Concept/0002 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader http://www.example.com/Concept/0001
```

I get:

```
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
http://www.example.com/Concept/0001
http://www.example.com/Concept/0002
http://www.example.com/Concept/0002
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
http://www.example.com/Concept/0001
http://www.example.com/Concept/0001
http://www.example.com/Concept/0002
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
```

and if I run the same query on these RDF triples:

```
http://www.example.com/Concept/0001 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader http://www.example.com/Concept/0002
http://www.example.com/Concept/0002 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#narrower http://www.example.com/Concept/0001
```

I get:

```
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
http://www.example.com/Concept/0002
http://www.example.com/Concept/0003
```

where as I expected it to return empty.

It looks like skos:broader+ seems to allow properties other than skos:broader, more like ANY*,skos:broader,ANY* or something....is that the correct behavior?

well I use:

```
Jena:       VERSION: 2.6.4
Jena:       BUILD_DATE: 2010-12-12T16:56:15+0000
ARQ:        VERSION: 2.8.7
ARQ:        BUILD_DATE: 2010-12-12T14:07:48+0000
```

Comment: That is an old version of Jena.  The implementation and semantics of + have changed quite a lot but the answers don't look right in the current version either.  Could you file a bug report with a working example (legal data, complete query) at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA

Comment: Thanks! I ran it on latest version of Jena (2.10.0 snapshot) and it works fine, so may be no need to file a bug...however it leads to a further question: Is Jena OWL-aware? I did skos:broader and skos:narrower and defined them as owl#TransitiveProperty and owl:inverseOf etc. and created a similar closed loop and Jena didn't discover it!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a minimal working example of this, here are two data files corresponding to those in the question.

data1.n3:

```
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix : <http://www.example.com/Concept/> .

:0001 skos:broader :0002 .
:0002 skos:broader :0003 .
:0003 skos:broader :0001 .
```

data2.n3:

```
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix : <http://www.example.com/Concept/> .

:0001 skos:broader :0002 .
:0002 skos:broader :0003 .
:0003 skos:narrower :0001 .
```

Using Jena's command line ARQ tools, it seems that the problem has been resolved in later versions of Jena/ARQ.

```
$ arq --version
Jena:       VERSION: 2.10.0
Jena:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000
ARQ:        VERSION: 2.10.0
ARQ:        BUILD_DATE: 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000

$ arq --query query.sparql --data data1.n3
---------
| sbj   |
=========
| :0002 |
| :0001 |
| :0003 |
---------

$ arq --query query.sparql --data data2.n3
-------
| sbj |
=======
-------
```